# How do I install StimulusJS to a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, stimulusjs

How do I install StimulusJS to a Ruby on Rails application?

The docs mention `webpack` and `npm`, but nothing about Rails or Yarn (at time of this writing).

(Kind of strange given that Stimulus comes from Basecamp, who literally created RoR...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer, at least for Rails 6, is stunningly easy:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install:stimulus
```

That's *it*.  That command will:

- invoke `yarn` to download and install StimulusJS
- add a line to `app/javascript/packs/application.js` to import javascript controllers
- add file `app/javascript/controllers/index.js` (to load/init all stimulus controllers)
- add a demo controller in `app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js`

From there, you can create a simple view to use the demo Hello controller, and with a little tweaking you can make it just like the demo on the [StimulusJS.org](http://StimulusJS.org) home page.

Webpacker instructions for Stimulus are here:
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/5-x-stable/docs/integrations.md#stimulus